# How to make "Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port XXXXX" into error?

Tags: ssh, forwarding

In most cases this is harmless message. In this case, this SSH connection exists solely to forward TCP ports (and it uses a dedicated key which is restricted to only be able to do this), and it should fail if it can't (then service manager will retry connecting until forwarding succeeds).

How to force SSH to consider all specified forwardings mandatory and fail hard if either one unsuccessful?

The system is Debian 11 and SSH is OpenSSH 8.4p1, if this matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run ssh with the option "-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes", or add "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" to your *.ssh/config* file.

The [ExitOnForwardFailure](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ExitOnForwardFailure) option causes `ssh` to exit with an error if it gets an error while setting up any forwardings:

> **ExitOnForwardFailure**
> Specifies whether ssh(1) should terminate the connection if it cannot set up all requested dynamic, tunnel, local, and remote port forwardings, (e.g. if either end is unable to bind and listen on a specified port). Note that **ExitOnForwardFailure** does not apply to connections made over port forwardings and will not, for example, cause ssh(1) to exit if TCP connections to the ultimate forwarding destination fail. The argument must be **yes** or **no** (the default).